# Page not validating because of xml in a script tag

Tags: html, xml, w3c-validation, script-tag

I'm trying to get a page to validate (http://validator.w3.org) and it complains about some xml I have inside a script tag.

How can I resolve this? Am I supposed to have something around the content of my script tag saying "don't look at me"?

> Line 68, column 114: end tag for
>   element "STR_PROCESSING" which is not
>   open
>
> >Processing....</STR_Processing>

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
var sML_XML='<STR_Processing>Processing....</STR_Processing><STR_OK>...';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place a backslash (`\`) before the slashes, when it is in a script.
Look here: http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#script

For example:
`var test="<b>something<\/b>";`
instead of:
`var test="<b>something</b>";`

This should validate with no errors.

Comment: +1. If you look directly under the error message output by the validator then you should see an "If this error occurs inside a script element" message that links to the Validator's own FAQ and then to that page.

Comment: @David Dorward, that's how I got that page. :) Long time ago I've seen it but forgot its address, but I remembered that I have navigated to it from the validator's page, so I've created a wrong code to get the error and the page's address. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tag in strings you can do this :

```
 var yourHTML = "<STR_PROCESSING>YourData<" + "/STR_PROCESSING>";
```

Comment: This works, but is inefficient. Escaping as per rhino's answer and the Validator's own FAQ is the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct XML way is to use CDATA section identifiers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
/* code */
//]]></script>
```

Comment: The error message is one that occurs when the document is HTML, not XHTML, so this wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: If it's HTML, I would use escape sequences instead of `<`, `>` and `&`: `\x3C`(<), `\x3E`(>) and `\x26`(&).

Comment: Only the `<` or the `/` would need to be escaped (it doesn't matter which one, the point is that `</` shouldn't appear inside an element defined by the DTD as containing CDATA), and a simple `\/` as per rhino's answer is all that is needed. Using Unicode escape sequences would just be time consuming and make the script more difficult to read.

Comment: Ok you win :p Those are not Unicode escape sequences. Unicode escape sequences looks like `\uNNNN`.